# On account creation, the message is not displayed

Tags: 7, users, emails

I try to register in my site; after a successful registration, I get redirected to the home page, but the following message is not displayed.

> Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.
>
> In the meantime, a welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address.

The standard core mail functionality is used, and no hook or rule is used for that registration.

Why doesn't the message appear?

I tried changing theme, but the message is still not appearing. Furthermore:

- The `$message` variable is available in the template file
- I am not using the [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost) module; I am using the [Mime Mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module to get HTML emails

How do i customize the message in some hooks?

Comment: @molot: Tried Purr Messages. Still it doesnt display anything.

Comment: @Ram seems you have exhausted my usual check-list for missing message. Sorry.

Comment: @Mołot: I have given this one,  'Visitors, but administrator approval is required' in the account settings.Mail and everything is working fine but message alone not working. in which hooks i can add that message to be displayed in home page after registration is successful?Any suggestions ?

Comment: well, if workarounds are acceptable then yes, I do. But please edit that little note into a question itself, OK? Don't want to get downvoted for going offtopic.

Comment: Are you redirecting to the home page in any certain special way?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to manually create [message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) in [`hook_user_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7), with code like:

```
function mymodule_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Account created, wait for approval.'), 'status');
}
```

Alternative place is [`hook_entity_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7):

```
function mymodule_entity_insert($entity, $type) {
  if ($type == 'user') {
    drupal_set_message(t('Account created, wait for approval.'), 'status');
  }
}
```

Problem is - it is possible that the same error will hide this one too. Benefit: it's easier to experiment with small custom hook, than to debug core.

Comment: Still same thing, i tried 'mymodule_user_insert' but it didn't show the message after registration

Comment: @Ram well, see the last paragraph ;) But now you can test if it at least writes to watchdog.

Comment: still no luck.No error messages too in watchdog.

Comment: @Ram If neither of these 2 hooks is ever fired for you (and that's how it looks, you can test it with `die()` to be sure), the problem is way deeper. It looks like some other module provides hook on the same action and somehow prevents yours (or even default) from firing. First time I hear about thing like that - I mean, I've seen conflict between 2 contrib modules, but never between contrib and core.